# Using DGV Cell painting. Enter number in a cell, OK. I then move to another cell and repeat with different number, OK but first number disappears

Tags: c#

private void dataGridView1_CellPainting_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{

```
        {
            string number = txtNumber.Text;
            if(number  != "" && X == e.ColumnIndex && Y == e.RowIndex)
            {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + 2, e.CellBounds.Y + 2, e.CellBounds.Width - 4, e.CellBounds.Height - 4);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, r);
                Font f = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font.FontFamily, 6);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(number, f, Brushes.Black, r);
                e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: did you check if the event is being fired (when editing  only the second cell) for more than one cell (I mean, not only the cell being edited but other cells at the same time)? (just using breakpoints to count events).

Comment: I shall try this out, thank you.